# Error Activating Accounts in Authentication System

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck in part 18 of [this Authentication tutorial](https://www.codecourse.com/library/lessons/php-authentication-system).
I did a `var_dump` on `$user` in the activate route, and it returned null. I don't know how to fix this. My code is included below:

```
<?php

$app->get('/activate', $guest(), function() use ($app) {

    $request = $app->request;

    $email = $request->get('email');
    $email = $request->get('identifier');

    $hashedIdentifier = $app->hash->hash($identifier);

    $user = $app->user->where('email', $email)
        ->where('active', false)
        ->first();
        var_dump($user);
        var_dump($user->active_hash);

    if (!$user || !$app->hash->hashCheck($user->active_hash, $hashedIdentifier)) {
        echo $hashedIdentifier;
        echo $user->active_hash;
    } else {
        $user->activateAccount();
        $app->render('auth/activate.php');
    }
})->name('activate');
```

Comment: You have two `where` calls when you create `$user`. Are you sure that your code lets you do that, or does the one perhaps override the other?

Comment: Yes I am sure that my code lets me do this

Comment: Then if `$user` is coming up null, strip everything out of your code and see what you get. Start off with `$user = $app->user->first()` and see if you get a value then; if you do, add one of the `where` calls back in. If you don't, then there's a problem with `$app->user`